# Android constraint layout childs not show in correct place in android vitual device?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I use constraint layout and material card view in it in my app.When i run app in read device it show correct and work fine(first image) but when i run it on android studio virtual device and genymotion device constraint layout childs get incorrect place and card view shows as black view! (seccond image).
Please help me.I confused!
[image: On real device]
[image: On virtual device!]
Layout XML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_back_8"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- Exit -->
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/menu_exit_card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/menu_item_corner"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ad_frame"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/menu_connect_us_card"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_x_small"
                android:src="@drawable/ico_exit"
                android:contentDescription="@string/exit"/>

            <custom_views.vajenameh.BoldTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="@color/menu_back_color"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/exit"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/menu_exit"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_item_back"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:onClick="menuClick"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
     <!-- Connect us-->
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/menu_connect_us_card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/menu_item_corner"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/menu_exit_card"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/menu_settings_card"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/menu_exit_card"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/menu_exit_card">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_x_small"
                android:src="@drawable/ico_connect_us"
                android:contentDescription="@string/connect_us"/>

            <custom_views.vajenameh.BoldTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="@color/menu_back_color"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/connect_us"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/menu_connect_us"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_item_back"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:onClick="menuClick"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
     <!-- Settings -->
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings_card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/menu_item_corner"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/menu_connect_us_card"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/menu_connect_us_card"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/menu_connect_us_card">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_x_small"
                android:src="@drawable/ico_settings"
                android:contentDescription="@string/settings"/>

            <custom_views.vajenameh.BoldTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="@color/menu_back_color"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/settings"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_item_back"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:onClick="menuClick"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    <!-- Favorite -->
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/menu_favor_card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/menu_item_corner"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/menu_exit_card"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/menu_words_index_card"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_x_small"
                android:src="@drawable/ico_favor"
                android:contentDescription="@string/favorites"/>

            <custom_views.vajenameh.BoldTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="@color/menu_back_color"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/favorites"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/menu_favor"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_item_back"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:onClick="menuClick"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
     <!-- Words index -->
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/menu_words_index_card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/menu_item_corner"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/menu_favor_card"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/menu_search_card"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/menu_favor_card"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/menu_favor_card">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_x_small"
                android:src="@drawable/ico_index"
                android:contentDescription="@string/index"/>

            <custom_views.vajenameh.BoldTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="@color/menu_back_color"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/index"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/menu_words_index"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_item_back"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:onClick="menuClick"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
     <!-- Search -->
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/menu_search_card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/menu_item_corner"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/menu_words_index_card"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/menu_words_index_card"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/menu_words_index_card">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_x_small"
                android:src="@drawable/ico_search"
                android:contentDescription="@string/search"/>

            <custom_views.vajenameh.BoldTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="@color/menu_back_color"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/search"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/menu_search"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_item_back"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:onClick="menuClick"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_frame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    </FrameLayout>
     <!-- Day word panel -->
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/day_word_panel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/menu_favor_card"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

            <custom_views.vajenameh.BoldTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/day_word"
                android:textColor="#212121"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_header" />

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <custom_views.vajenameh.BoldTextView
                        android:id="@+id/day_word_word_tv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/word_word_test"
                        android:textColor="#212121"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_sub_header" />

                    <custom_views.vajenameh.NormalTextView
                        android:id="@+id/day_word_meaning_tv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/word_meaning_test"
                        android:textColor="#212121"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_explain" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/menu_back_color"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_updateBtn_iv"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/ic_dimen_small"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_dimen_small"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_small"
                android:src="@drawable/ico_update"
                android:contentDescription="TODO" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"></FrameLayout>

            <custom_views.vajenameh.BoldTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_small"
                android:text="@string/header_title"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_header" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/boldTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/blackboard_5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/menu_favor_card"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Without your layout and the code populating the views this is unanswerable.

Comment: @GabeSechan i added layout xml code

Comment: Looks like a problem with the FrameLayouts. What is `@drawable/menu_item_back`? For a test, set the visibility of the FrameLayouts to `invisible` to see if the contents of the cards show up.